# script execution omits commands

Tags: powershell

I have a small script to get information about a network computer in my domain but during the execution the script omits two lines.

```
$HostName = Read-Host 'Veuillez donner le nom du poste que vous voulez verifier?'

If (Test-Connection $HostName -count 4 -quiet) 
{
    Write 'The host responded';
    gwmi win32_volume -ComputerName $HostName -Filter 'drivetype = 3' | select driveletter, label, @{LABEL='GBfreespace';EXPRESSION={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.freespace/1GB)} };
    Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $HostName | Select-Object PSComputerName, Description, OSArchitecture;
    Get-ADComputer $HostName | select DistinguishedName;
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Computer $HostName | Format-Table -Property Name, Version, InstallDate, Vendor;
}
else
{
    Write 'The host doesn''t responded';
}
```

The problem does not seems to be in the commands (I get the desired result by typing them directly in the console), but in the position of the command.

I tried to invert the order of the commands and the result was always like this:

After the `if` statement:

- the two first commands are displayed
- the 3rd and the 4th are omitted
- the last one is again displayed

I also tried it like this:

```
If (Test-Connection $HostName -count 4 -quiet) 
{
    Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $HostName | Select-Object PSComputerName, Description, OSArchitecture;
    Get-ADComputer $HostName | select DistinguishedName;    
    Get-ADComputer $HostName | select DistinguishedName;    
    Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $HostName | Select-Object PSComputerName, Description, OSArchitecture;
    Get-ADComputer $HostName | select DistinguishedName;        

    Write 'The host responded';
    gwmi win32_volume -ComputerName $HostName -Filter 'drivetype = 3' | select driveletter, label, @{LABEL='GBfreespace';EXPRESSION={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.freespace/1GB)} };

    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Computer $HostName | Format-Table -Property Name, Version, InstallDate, Vendor;
}
```

After the `if` statement:

- the command 1 is displayed
- the commands 2 and 3 are omitted
- the 4th command is displayed
- the 5th command is  again omitted
- the 6th is displayed
- the 7th is omitted and finally the 8th is displayed

Comment: You're a victim of auto-formatting - powershell will apply output formatting based on the first object. Since the first object "out the door" so to speak is one with the properties `PSComputerName, Description, OSArchitecture`, only these property values will be shown for subsequent objects. It's not that the output is not there, the formatting subsystem is just not showing them to you